# Bootstrap dropdown-menu prevented keys

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an input field that shows suggestions with a dropdown menu while i type. My example is simpified, but the problem is the same.
If I have focus on the top menu item and press the arrow up key I would like to set focus on the input field (without closing the menu).
It seems like Bootstrap is preventing event bubbeling of some of the keys.

The escape key is just for testing. It's the arrow up key I want to use.

You can find a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/connyake/ffpydrrh/).

```
EVENT       KEY        RESULT
keypress    [any]      not working
keydown     arrowup    not working
keydown     escape     working
keyup       arrowup    working, but will move focus when on second item too
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" id='AAAA'>AAAA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BBBB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CCCC</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.form-control').bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
        if ($('.dropdown').hasClass('open')) {
            $('#AAAA').focus();
        } else {
            $('.dropdown').addClass('open');
        }
    }
});

$('#AAAA').bind('keyup', function(event) {
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'ArrowUp':
            $('.form-control').focus();
            break;
        case 'Escape':
            $('.form-control').focus();
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I first closed the dropdown ( removed the open class ) and then focused on the input. It seems to be working now.

```
$('#AAAA').bind('keydown', function(event) {
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'ArrowUp':
                $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
                $('input').focus();
            break;
        case 'Escape':
                $('.form-control').focus();
            break;
    }
});
```

**Edit ( After you updated your question ):** `keydown` is being used by bootstrap. You can bind all events on `keyup`. `keyup` event fires after `keydown` so you don't need to use `setTimeout()`

```
$('#AAAA').bind('keyup', function(event) {
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'ArrowUp':
                $('.form-control').focus();
            break;
        case 'Escape':
                $('.form-control').focus();
            break;
    }
});
```

**Edit 2 ( Solves the: If you press the up key when on the second item, you will release the key on the first item and it will set focus on the input )** I kept the use of `setTimeout()` to let bootstrap complete its own working. This will also let `keypress` work from bottom to input. [jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/L1Lnm1ah/)

```
$('.dropdown').on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', function(e) {

  var index = $(this).find('li:not(.disabled):visible a').index(e.target);

  if (!index && e.which == 38) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.form-control').focus();
    }, 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul Dev. It's a nice sollution except that I want the menu to remain open. I've updated the question. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Sorry but your update wont work as i describe in my question. If you press the up key when on the second item, you will release the key on the first item and it will set focus on the input.

Comment: @ConnyOlsson I updated the answer again. Now it will flow properly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this until anyone can find a better solution. I wrapped the focus() in a timer.

```
$('#AAAA').bind('keydown', function(event) {
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'ArrowUp':
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.form-control').focus();
            }, 1);
            break;
        case 'Escape':
            $('.form-control').focus();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I have updated the above answer to work as per your needs.